# validate MPD file - using MPEG-DASH

Tags: streaming, iso, mpeg, mpd, mpeg-dash

I have just started using MPEG-DASH (from the client side), following the c057623_ISO_IEC_23009-1_2012 spec.

Does anyone know if there is a public lib or open source to validate MPD file I receive?

I have no problem in processing the xml.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check this [MPEG-DASH MPD Validator](http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?page_id=605)
The DASH Industry Forum provides [great software resources](http://dashif.org/software/) for all things MPEG DASH.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful!
I was looking for an open source code that will help me process the code.
I have found it in this site - the libdash project.

Comment: It's quite interesting for the MPEG-DASH MPD Validator. I tried one .mpd file from dashif (http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/ftp/datasets/mmsys12/BigBuckBunny/MPDs/) but it failed!?

Comment: @Drake - You are right, I have tried myself few validated mpd files, and they failed, it keeps telling me 'Cannot find the declaration of element ‘MPD'. I think it fails due to the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> at the start of the file

Comment: @Darke - do you have more links to mpd files?
I have fond the following examples but could use more: http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.0.0/index.html http://digitalprimates.net/dash/DashTest.html 
https://dash-mse-test.appspot.com/dash-player.html

Comment: @inbaly You can get a lot .mpd files on Internet. I just noticed if you make all letters non-capital in *xmlns* and *profiles*, some .mpd files can pass this validator ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here another MPD Validator from dashif: [DASHIF Validator](http://dashif.org/conformance.html).

In respect to the error "Cannot find the declaration of element ‘MPD'" provided by the mentioned [MPEG-DASH MPD Validator](http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?page_id=605), I observed it may happen even when the MPD tag is present, but it encounters some differences to the expected text, such as:

```
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011" ...>
```

instead of

```
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" ...>
```